# jquery checkbox checked property and ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, properties, ternary-operator

- Windows 7
- VisualStudio 2015
- C# .Net MVC
- jquery 3.1.1

I must be missing something trivial.  I have a checkbox and on it I set a `data` element that holds the "id" number (index) of the item.  I have the `on change` method below

```
 1      $("input#item_IsHere").on("change",
 2          function () {
 3              var index = $(this).data("index");
 4              var checked = $(this).checked === true ? 1 : 0;
 5
 6              console.log("on change: " + $(this).checked);
 7              //...
 8          });
```

When I click the checkbox the change method fires and `index` is set as I expect. What I didn't expect is that the `checked` property of `$(this)` would be undefined.

I have also tried a fiddle for this but the fiddle worked :/

I am seeing this in Chrome and Firefox.  When the page loads I see the checkbox and bring up the developer tools debugger.  In the debugger I set a breakpoint on the `console.log` (lise 6).  When I click the checkbox it runs to the breakpoint and waits.  I can hover over the first `$(this)` (line 3) and I can see that the `checked` property is set to `true` in this case.

The issue is that the value of `var checked` ends up being 0 and the result of the `console.log` is

```
    on change: undefined
```

Oh, I've also done the ternary operator on line 4 as

```
    var checked = $(this).checked ? 1 : 0;
and
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
and
    if ($(this).checked) {
        checked = 1;
    } else {
        checked = 0;
    }
```

with the same results.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: There is no function `checked` in jQuery. Use this instead `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$("input").is(":checked")`

```js
var checked = $("input:eq(0)").is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;

console.log(checked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

Comment: Sigh, I tried `.is(":checked") ` just before posting the question and it failed... I ran it again just now and it worked. Thank you all.

Comment: Not a problem, please mark this question as answered

Comment: yep, would do but it has been marked as a duplicate.  Thanks all the same.